# Filling in tikz between a curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

How would one fill between the lines of f(x)=-1/x ?

This is my code so far...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{8cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [  
        width=8cm,
        height=8cm,
        axis lines=center, 
        domain=-5:5,
        samples=100,
        xmin=-5, xmax=5,
        ymin=-5, ymax=5 
       ]

        \addplot[smooth, thick] {-(1/x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A graph of $\hat{V}(r)\approx -\frac{1}{r}$}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean fill between the lines of? Between the graph and the axis?

Comment: Between the positive part of f(x)=-1/x and the negative part

Comment: There is a fillbetween library, the usage is explained with many examples in the pgfplots manual. Basically, you use 'name path=A' in the addplot options, then add a second plot with 'name path=B' and a third plot with \addplot fill between[of=A and B]; Then the area between the first two plots is filled.

Comment: @JLo0815, this won't work out of the box, because there is no continuous line crossing the y-axis. It _might_ be a working approach though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will produce what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{8cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [  
        set layers, axis on top,
        width=8cm,
        height=8cm,
        axis lines=center, 
        domain=-5:5,
        samples=100,
        xmin=-5, xmax=5,
        ymin=-5, ymax=5 
       ]

        % draw the curve
        \addplot[smooth, thick, samples=100] {-(1/x)};

        % generate the required paths
        \addplot[smooth, thick, domain=-5:-0.1, name path=A, draw=none] {-(1/x)} -- (axis cs: 5, 5);
        \addplot[smooth, thick, domain=5:0.1, name path=B, draw=none] {-(1/x)} -- (axis cs: -5, -5);

        % fill
        \addplot[green] fill between [of=A and B];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A graph of $\hat{V}(r)\approx -\frac{1}{r}$}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

Apart from what you have, you will have to add some things:

- As [JLo0815](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/42690/jlo0815) noted, you can use the **`fillbetween`** library. However, the 1/x function is not continuous, so you have to extend the path manually. I did this by continuing the paths to the maximum of your x/y-range.
- To get the axis shown, you will need to add the **`set layers`** and `axis on top` style.

Furthermore, be careful with what you are doing: Plotting 1/x produces, very high numbers **close to zero**, which is why I used 0.1 as domain limits for the paths, otherwise you will end up with

> ! Dimension too large

errors. Also, as you appear to know (or you were just lucky) you will need to use an **even number of samples**, otherwise x=0 will be included, which will (obviously) fail, too.

And finally, the resulting graph:

[image]

Oh, and last, but not least: Please provide a *working* MWE next time, including `\documentclass` and packages.